# Cómo implemento Thread usando Xamarin en Visual Studio para ejecutar dos procesos en paralelo?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, hilos, xamarin.forms

Se tiene una Activity para iniciar sesión en una aplicación, la idea es usar hilos para ejecutar dos procesos de manera simultanea.

Al ingresar nombre de usuario y contraseña se abrirá un cuadro de diálogo, informándole al usuario que la solicitud se está llevando a cabo; mientras que en otro hilo se debe realizar la autentificación, consumiendo un WebService:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al momento de debuggear me aparece la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué estoy haciendo mal? de qué otra manera se puede implementar Thread sin que aparezca la excepción y se ejecuten los procesos de forma paralela?

NOTA: threadIniciandoSesion() se invoca en otra función en donde se realiza la autentificación de usuario.

Comment: Hola Jovany, mira [ask] para aprender a hacer mejores preguntas. Te recomiendo que quites las mayusculas del titulo, que cambies la foto por el codigo en texto y el error a parte. Un saludo

Comment: Utiliza métodos async await para la petición al servidor y para el progressBar utiliza this.RunOnUIThread(() => alertDialog.show());

Answer (score 0):

Si quisieras usar procesamiento en paralelo, podrías echarle un vistaso a la clase Parallel: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.8

Particularmente en lo que estás haciendo, yo utilizaría el método Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread para actualizar la UI en forma asincrónica mientras sigo con el proceso de la autenticación por otro lado:

```
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread
            ( async () =>
            {
                lblStatus.Text = message;
            }
            );
```